# how to handle when unknown socket.io event

Tags: node.js, socket.io

i have following code server side.

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(8080);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.on('event', function(data){
     // process...
  });
});
```

client side (part)

```
socket.emit('event', {type:'command', data:'data....'});
for (var i=0; i<=9999999; i++){
  socket.emit('unknownEvent', {'type':'attack', data:'a34tagfa3wtasfd'});
}
```

now, how to handle and defence 'unknownEvent' event...?..

Comment: wt do u meant by unknown event..if u emit the event in client means in server side u can handle that event by socket.on('urEventName',urFun);

Comment: If there is no event handler registered for that particular event, nothing happens on the server.

Upon request receipt , the event emitter<serverside socket> try to see if there are handlers registered for this event. 

If none are found it just returns.

Comment: 'unknown' event to massive rising, i want to disconnect that socket. massive request(include empty event) is heavy server load... i'm afraid to client's malicious attacks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Older question, but was running into the similar thing so I figured I would share a way to do it.

## Client Side

So on the client instead of passing the event as the first argument to emit, use a generic event name, like `event` or something. I ended up using the name of the app since it was short. Then in the data object, pass in the name of the function you want to call.

So this:

```
socket.emit('awesomeSocketEvent', {hello: 'world'});
```

Becomes:

```
socket.emit('genericEvent', {event:'awesomeSocketEvent', hello:'world'});
```

Rewriting everything on the client side sucks, and my client stuff was mostly just `emit`-ing so I wrapped the socket.io client in another object with it's own emit event that did the change in event names and data objects.

## Server Side

Now on the server side there's only ever going to be one custom event called, `genericEvent`, so the custom events need to be restructured as properties of an object. Once that happens its a simple check to see if the event exists in the object, call it if it does, or do something else if it doesn't.

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

    var events = {
        awesomeSocketEvent: function(data){
            // do your socket stuff here
        }
    };

    socket.on('genericEvent', function(data){
        if(data.event in events){
            events[data.event](data);
        } else {
            // do your unknown event stuff here
        }
    });

});
```

After looking at the code while writing that portion, I'm not sure about performance with having the events object being declared within the connect event. It might be better to declare `events` outside of the connection event and then pass in `socket` to all of your functions.

Answer (score 0):

As Gntem said, if the server-side Socket.io doesn't have a registered event handler, then the event will just return and nothing will handle it.

If you're looking for more protection (you expect someone to spam you with unregistered events, for example), you might consider using a middleware that checks to see if the event name is valid (or tests other qualities). Something like this:

```
const socketChecker = {
    someEvent:true,
}

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.use((packet, next) => {
        if(socketChecker[packet[0]] === true){
            next()
        } else {
            //Disconnect user here
        }
    });
    socket.on('someEvent',function(){
        //do work here
    })
});
```

Note that if you do this, you're reading packets that may have reserved names, (like heartbeat, connect, message, json, etc).

Here's the reference for packets:
http://gevent-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/packet.html

Note that I'm not actually using this, so I have no idea what issues may come up with it. I just checked to see where the event name was located in some of the packets. Further documentation should be found (or more testing should be done) regarding what's actually going on inside those packets.

Answer (score -1):

if the client-side or server-side `Socket.io` have no registered handlers for that event then it will not handle it, meaning it will return and do anything.

But in case that the client sends a non registered event to server, you can always use the `message` event on client-side or server-side for each message received.

```
socket.on('message',function(m){console.log(m);});
```

Comment: The first half of your answer is correct, but the second half about the non-registered event doesn't work since they are emitting a custom event. Tested in v.9.13, probably the same in v1.